# PHP cURL is holding onto session cookies

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies

So this is pretty strange. I'm making a cURL login script and I need my cookies to be exactly what I send to cURL. But it seems cURL is holding on in memory to old cookies, even AFTER the cookie file is completely truncated.

In the output below, notice that I'm trying to hit `amazon.co.uk` but my previous cookies from `amazon.com` are still at the top of the cookie file. And that is enough to make Amazon not keep my logged in. So I need fresh cookies.

Now, this first cookie output you see is the starting point. Which is what happens *Everytime* I refresh the page. **Even though** The final cookie output is not this. It's just the `amazon.co.uk` cookies.

The reason the other cookies are "working" is because on the login page, (where you see "need clean session". I'm calling `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);`  Which properly sends ONLY the cookies from the file.

But AFTER that point, when i'm not calling that anymore, it goes back to these stored cookies. I can't call COOKIESESSION every time, because I need it remember the cookies from request to request.

So basically, i just need a way to clear out cURLs memory of the cookies, or something along that line. And before you say "delete the file" you can see from the output that I am clearing out the cookie file.

```
string(125706) "
string(78) "https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/fba/core/data/collections/shipments.html"
string(12) "need to init"
string(1704) "# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.amazon.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875358  session-id-time 1429858800l
.amazon.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875358  session-id  181-0028548-4275101
.amazon.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875532  ubid-main   191-9297218-7050950
.amazon.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875358  session-token   cL5vcznqgzk2RwhZIFZjSepKiznVnNcdv1Uh/FiLV8i0QuxpPEEx5D94imjktXu69QOdfQuQX8chNhvB8sR9KI4ZgJBWWlMnFOepyO6/+wtH9GOtH+1WMZQKHp8fqGJlpMtT8XMwKUx+hnuYRPnheq54s5Q1fQX5HJ4wS3KE4UVHAady2H4ugSsIi+O33zL1d3eWN4TnbX4nxiHqIqFs4Q8GGCYVEwOrbcB1KH3FCohbrwQPXNN7igf6jQXI++h0N0dJTv781sU=
.amazon.com TRUE    /   FALSE   2059990558  x-main  "i6iLU3A?45qEpvgw@NNzGTsxqqOvwryX"
.amazon.com TRUE    /   TRUE    2059990557  at-main 5|7HZSLL/JbN/aGiGYXo/uxjxNFyLucyEmxBCKkR4QoU06R5NF4I1eNekoJpsyE2hkx5FrSI3dP5DuaolT5D48jdz6NLwDmYdKzovka+5DJTHuRuVmzBVVkW2g40uhZlRlaHJmewKWCjmoyi+azkQswRDRmfyAICX+hBrRfUwJRwQqeOhQGc6dujYHDBiv8nxcQFciY9G+7au3zYAGof+CepYeiWk4xuQmBLobVAci10frgDxdgV7OdJOSVaHz2UtykTQ+F4V4hNzFwclsv9ranLMSM5KH9tys
.amazon.com TRUE    /   TRUE    0   sess-at-main    "GR5GAfuX5U+vC3ayUz3LIUs7+o414SBlsEA1rVMyvvA="
.amazon.com TRUE    /   FALSE   2059990557  lc-main en_US
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875575  session-id-time 1429858800l
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875575  session-id  276-1602919-0207204
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876234  ubid-acbuk  277-6716334-7531852
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429875881  session-token   gVQymTdZsxCD0I/aObEZCLmujDKZGjQ48lGc34xaW6i45XVIonC1YK014YrFqVvNG2qurp1xmGrtCHcuVQx2tSQ7LlYpr+srdgyKvj/pCcW6CxR0azqQsU9wYW3BxXqZnQDQnqVmYaGpY0eB19BOTShppMKGnPhzMkgy/UFVuoeGsngx0tz8iWFMy6qTZFqibPoMvFmpsdsL8GhbVn6sy++vUUBeQhVgyzktWEfjRXdzZw32t/SOCA==
"
string(21) "unexpected login page"
string(78) "https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/fba/core/data/collections/shipments.html"
string(12) "need to init"
string(0) ""
string(25) "no cookies, need to login"
string(51) "https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/homepage.html"
string(0) ""
string(28) "on login, need clean session"
string(44) "https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/ap/widget"
string(270) "# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876317  session-id-time 1429858800l
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876317  session-id  278-1385775-5645645
"
string(112) "https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/utilities/set-rainier-prefs.html?ie=UTF8&url=&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P"
string(1212) "# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876318  session-id-time 1429858800l
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876318  session-id  278-1385775-5645645
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876318  ubid-acbuk  279-4986453-7111520
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   1429876318  session-token   YpneIOOGKiqQ8x/E/soTTmUAym3tXUWGtjXKYWnAONOkcHENmQxMDD3zTWjgtLN9b/em0xBTPoYMpECUcR38rZlf2Vu1a2TOBNsi2hpTjageCvIM9noPlEq0TBrgdOEfGl354j0+dIfTHM4ObUF2nzY2UBubZoi3X77MBcpLel+rjjCFeTCwhmNFbru5dyalIRn1UyVAdsB3PIEk+saDDbf2HRMUFP7hdaCaBhKwb5tpyvpA1xrk2XJXm2dre2FE1MKsgWFwt1c=
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   2059991518  x-acbuk 3IkDIKmc71d9lKFefDy7ATw1QKYl8545
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   TRUE    2059991518  at-acbuk    "5|/QlP2Fp+YlPLm1O0znctkujc6sMDGnEGxbqVjtrNehg2P98QG1vCFOkKxChCaUJzPmQSS4C/87WM0XC30721BVwFLpKRa9FIS9sUtlZJh8m07RHhC2vBspsYjZ710LfM/cHCHKXdBmXlHZ8CLNO55ff4oYRI5NnaFKu8dx2xSBdwAzYydTqlQhrOKE0RAolHBJgIVngWDlw42kDY79FOciZP7ray/qSR/eceAPfJfzIV0t/vKC/vWpNlOQBs/FTmvWmEMZtSoAUWlgPeIiUw+g=="
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   TRUE    0   sess-at-acbuk   "9EziH1irfB0flBfODA2zw+lVgvo4OmENH4XM3kxEnpg="
.amazon.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   2059991518  lc-acbuk    en_US
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

When there is trouble, I often set `FOLLOWLOCATION` to false:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

If there is a Redirect you can see what is happening and need get cookies that are set in the Redirected URL's Response Header then `FOLLOWLOCATION` must be set to false.

When the curl URL takes you to a redirect `curl_getinfo` will get the redirect location URL.

```
$status = intval(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
if ($status > 299 && $status < 400){
  $url= curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL );
}
// update cookies, do not clear `cookies()`;
```

---

When it gets tough I uses these options to get both Response and Response Headers. The Response Header will be return in the `curl_exec()` data.  The Request Header will be return by `curl_getinfo()`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data =  substr($data,$skip);
  $filename = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
  $filename .= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) . '.txt';
  $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
  fwrite($fp,$info\n$data");
  fclose($fp);

  $data =  substr($data,$skip);
}
```

Both header and the HTML are stored in the file.  You can then view both HTTP Headers, the HTML and JavaScript.  Sometimes cookies are set by JavaScript document.cookie, or the page redirected with window.location, or an HTML form's submit button is clicked with JS.  In these cases it may be necessary to scrape the cookies and or redirect location from the curl data.

---

Then I use FireFox Inspector or Chrome Development Tool.

I go to the Network Tab

In FireFox I go to Settings and turn on "Enable Persistent logs"
In Chrome I click "Preserve log" on the Network Tab

Then I use the Browser to go wherever I want curl to go.

Now I can see every Request and Response including redirects and compare them with the save headers.

---

When you need the header to look exactly like the saved Browser headers:

Create an array to put the Request Header Key Values
Fill in the Request array with exactly what is in the Request header of your upload.
**EXAMPLE:**

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

Add to curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

---

Many times it is much easier to use a mobile version. Many times the  desktop version page requires JavaScript and the mobile version does not.  I use FireFox with user agent switcher using an old Motorola user agent to retrieve the headers and HTML.  Then I use the same user agent in curl's `HTTPHEADER`:

```
request[] = 'User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
```

**end of update**

---

I find curl's cookie jar problematic so I wrote my own routine.
For this `CURLOPT_HEADER` must be true.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data =  substr($data,$skip);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = strpos($requestHeader,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($requestHeader,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($requestHeader,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
  }
```

Then to use the $cookies[]:

```
 $cookie = '';
 $show = '';
 $delim = '';
 foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
   $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
   $delim = '; ';
 }
```

Then use $cookie:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
```

Comment: Trying to get this to work, note that my headers say "Set-cookie" not Set-Cookie. Going to replace your strpos with stripos

Comment: use `stripos` (case insensitive)  rather than strpos then it will work with both.  I've used this a lot and never ran into a problem so must not have encounter a small case c.

Comment: Also $head is used in the while loop, but never defined. Is that supposed to be $requestHeader?

Comment: That should be requestHeader, I changed head to requestHeader so it would be more obvious to others.  My code uses $head

Comment: Also you can't check boolean on strpos without a === false. What you have in there is an infinite loop.  Mind updating those 2 things (=== false and $head for others looking at this?)

Comment: But that case cannot happen, the request header would have to start with Set-Cookie.  You only need `=== false` if it is possible the search term is at the very beginning of the string being searched.

Comment: That creates a warning to let you know you may have a typo, it's not an error.  Depends on where you have set your error reporting.  I exclude  E_NOTICE in my error_reporting and will not get that notification. And I use the same block of code and do not want to clear previous cookies when redirected.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work for me.  Amazon doesn't recognize the cookie string as a valid session. For some reason it works fine with cookiejar to login, but not with sending the cookies like this.  I've checked the string, checked my saved file, checked the request, all looks fine. Amazon just doesn't like it.

Comment: You cannot use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true` or you miss the cookies from the redirect.  I've cracked tougher cookies than Amazon.  I'm tempted to create an account just for the challenge.  Yep, they set a cookie in the 302 redirect.

Comment: You're awesome. So answer me this - Why does my login work fine with COOKIEJAR and FOLLOWCATION set to true. But you're saying if you set cookies straight up to have it set to false?

Comment: curl should and will get the cookies.   If it works with FOLLOWLOCATION, true, then great.  But if you were to use my method of getting the cookies it has to be false and curl will not follow the redirect but stop and give you the headers and cookies.  You grab the redirect URL location from `curl_info()` and do another curl request rather than let curl follow.